# How to run a .pl test on C project in Eclipse on Windows?

Tags: c, eclipse, perl, testing

I have to make a C (not C++) project to the specifications given by my teacher.
To allow us to test this project he has given us a .pl file that should test the project and a folder full of .in and .out files.

I work on a Win10 machine and has Eclipse for C installed (Kepler).

How can I set up my project to run the provided test?
Do I need to change anything in the test since I don't work on Linux and not from a cmdl?

The program is a train travel planner.

Here is the .pl file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my ( $createmode ) = @ARGV;
my $testdir = "./tests";

if( defined($createmode) ) {
    if($createmode cmp "create") {
    print "Brug:\n";
    print "\tcheck.pl         - tests if your programs output matches .out-filerne\n";
    print "\tcheck.pl create  - makes new .out-files (deletes the excisting files!)\n";
    exit();
    }
    $createmode=1;
}

# print "$testdir/tests.tst";
open(TESTS, "$testdir/tests.tst");


my $koereplan;
my $startst;
my $slutst;

while (<TESTS>) {

    /([\w\d]+)\.in\s+\"(.+)\"\s+\"(.+)\"/ && do {
    $koereplan="$testdir/$1";
    $startst=$2;
    $slutst=$3;

    # print $koereplan."\t".$startst."\t".$slutst."\n";

    open(RUN, "./travelplanning $koereplan.in '$startst' '$slutst' |");
    my $cost=0;
    while(<RUN>) {
        /^(\d+)\s+(\d+)$/ && do {
        $cost=$1+$2*15;
        }
    };

    #print "Cost fra programmet: $cost";

    my $outfile="$koereplan.$startst.$slutst.out";
    # print $outfile."\n";
    if($createmode) {
        open(OUT, ">$outfile") or die "Couldn't open '$outfile' for writing";
    } else {
        open(IN, "<$outfile") or die "Couldn't open '$outfile' for reading";
    }
    if($createmode) {
        print OUT "$cost\n";
    } else {
        my $facit=<IN>;
        if($facit cmp "$cost\n") {
        chomp $facit;
        print "ERROR: $koereplan.in $startst $slutst gav $cost og facit er $facit.\n";
        #last;
        } else {
        chomp $facit;
        print "SUCCES: $koereplan.in $startst $slutst gav $cost og facit er $facit.\n";
        };
    };
    };
}
```

Some names are in Danish, sorry about that. Koereplan = timetable, slut = end.

Excample of the .in files:

```
Esbjerg,    07:48
Bramming,   08:00
Vejen,      08:15
Kolding,    08:30
Middelfart, 08:45
Odense,     09:14
Nyborg,     09:29
Korsør,     09:42
Slagelse,   09:53
Sorø,       10:01
Ringsted,   10:10
Roskilde,   10:26
Høje Taastrup,  10:34
Valby,      10:42
København H,    10:48
```

This is just station names and departure times.

The .out files just contain one number each, the number of minutes the corresponding trip will take.

The scaffold project also came with makefile files, but I haven't been able to use them in my environment, I have simply taken the "business-files" to another project made in Eclipse, and that works fine for compiling and running the project in Eclipse. But that doesn't allow me to use the test script (that I currently can't even open in Eclipse).

If you feel it helps, here is the assignment: [assignment on course website](http://imada.sdu.dk/~jamik/dm510-16/assignment1.php)

But I think I can solve the assignment itself, it's using the teachers test I'm unsure about how to do.

Comment: Do you have perl installed? https://www.perl.org/get.html#win32 Do you have make/gcc/etc installed? http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php If you have those things, your assignment instructions should work fine. You can even run the different make targets in Eclipse CDT with the "make" view http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_make_targets_view.htm?cp=10_4_0_4 and one final piece of advice, upgrade Eclipse, use Mars instead of Kepler, it is 2 years newer

Comment: I have now installed perl and I already had mingw installed. But I must admit, I have no clue what these make targets are or how I use them. Previously I have just built my project and ran it from the run-button. That works when there are just .c and .h files and one with a main function in it.

Comment: Ok, it seems I needed to add C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin to my PATH.
Now I at least get a new error that I haven't seen before.

Comment: I would still like to know how I can run the test.

Comment: Try starting your msys shell, make sure the PATH has gcc/make/perl. Then cd to the directory containing the skeleton and type `make test` and or `make testrun`

Comment: lets move this to chat and I can see if I can help a bit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104408/discussion-between-jonah-graham-and-kitalda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start Eclipse CDT choose 1 of these methods:

1. Start eclipse from the terminal that works, e.g.:

   $ /path/to/eclipse.exe &
2. Make sure msys and mingw's bin directories are in the PATH and start eclipse the "normal" way

Then you can import your project as a new C Project and build/debug/run within CDT as normal:

1. Choose *File* menu | *New*  | *Makefile Project with Existing Code*

[image]

2. Enter path to your project and name. But leave indexer settings as `<none>`* and press *Finish*

[image]

3. Open the `Make Target` view
4. Right-click on the project and choose *New...*

[image]

5. Fill in the target you want to build
6. Double-click on the new green icon and the build will run with the output in the Console view.

[image]

- Something seems strange in CDT, if I use the obvious setting of *MinGW GCC* for indexer settings, then I can't do make properly as CDT is insisting on using internal builder.